# Lost samba connection on Windows 10 machine after samba update

Tags: ubuntu, windows, samba

I have an Ubuntu based server, that I use as a fileserver.
I have three samba shares with three different users that I have successfully connected to with my Windows 10 machine (through Hamachi).
Recently I updated my samba to version 4.5.4 and now I can't connect reliably to the shares anymore. So I do some digging around and find out that ntlmv1 support is dropped if not specified in the config anymore. Windows should have ntlmv2 support so I do some more digging and find out I need to set the Registry value LmCompatibilityLevel to 5 (it was 1 before.)
[here's the link](https://kb.iu.edu/d/atcb)

I succesfully connect to the samba share, but now I can't move, copy, add, remove or rename any files on the share. (Gives me the error 0x8007003B) The user has necessary rights and and was working normaly before the update.
If I add the line `ntlm auth = yes` to the samba config and change the registery bit back to 1 everything works as expected.

So my question is, how can I continue to use the share normaly with ntlmv1 disabled? As using it is insecure and I have other people roaming on the same Hamachi share, using ntlmv2 would be nice. (I thought it was enabled by default before, but apparently not.)

Edit-
I updated to samba v4.5.8 and now I'm able to copy etc. small files to the share. (When the bit is set to 5 and ntlm~ is removed) Large files still refuse to work with the above error.

I'm using the latest Windows 10 preview (16184.1001)
Samba version 4.5.8